# jQuery Cycle Effect on Tabs

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a built this Jquery code.

I want the buttons to auto cycle insted of hovering can anyone help please?

Jquery code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
  var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
  $items.click(function() {
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var index = $items.index($(this));
    $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
  }).eq(1).mouseover();
});
```

The Html is as follows:

```
<div id="vtab">
  <ul>
    <li class="home selected"></li>
    <li class="login"></li>
    <li class="support"></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <h4>Home Insurance</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Secure Login</h4>
    <form id="loginForm" action="">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>You need to sign in with your Email & Password to continue.</legend>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="login" type="submit" value="Fake Login" />
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Online Support</h4>
    Maecenas in varius nulla....
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the buttons to cycle through rather than just when you hover

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community, please take the time to read through the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also, please post the raw code instead of the broken link. If you want your question to be worth answering, you need to invest some time into actually asking it.

Comment: "auto cycle" is not enough to gauge what you really want. Please put some effort into explaining your requirements.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I would like the tabs to cycle through automatically starting with tab1 then move to tab2 then move to tab3 then back to tab1

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want to automatically cycle through a set of tabs. Fortunately, the jQuery UI team has provided us with a great tool call [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) that can do just this. More specifically, there's a method in Tabs called [`.rotate()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-rotate) which will allow you to provide and interval (in ms) and a command to repeat the cycle once it has finished.

The example code provided on the [Tabs page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) resembles your code very closely, which should make it relatively painless to implement the jQuery UI solution.

Comment: @Chris You would scrap what you've written and instead go with the jQuery UI code, which is super-simple. It will end up looking something like `$("#vtab").tabs()` with a couple options passed in.

Comment: hi Jonathan I tried implementing that method with no success, I am very frustrated.

Comment: @Chris What did you have a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

can't see your page.  Can you re-post the url?

I have built one here.  Take a look and see is that what you want:
http://www.castlerockinvestments.ca/dev/index_banner.jsp

If that's what you want, you might need to change the source code yourself because I ch.  The writer of JQuery cycle got sample code for a lot of option there.  I assume you see them all already :  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager-over.html